# Extract Only Date from timestamp in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a '*timestamp without time zone*' value in a column example:

```
PunchIn = "2019-06-10 09:10:00"
```

How can I extract "2019-06-10 00:00:00" from this column?

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=50d3d0d21858a307d4a4120ca4985e67)

```
SELECT my_date::date::timestamp
```

This converts the date column `my_date` to date (cuts the time part) and if you cast it back into `timestamp` it gets the 0 time.

Alternatively you can use the `date_trunc` function:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', my_date)
```

Comment: @Sajeev Did this answer help you? If not, how can I help? If so, please do not forget to accept (close) and upvote the helpful answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT SUBSTRING("PunchIn = '2019-06-10 09:10:00'" FROM 11 FOR 21);`
should return the string you're looking for (if I count the index number right:)

You can use the DATE function to extract date:

`SELECT DATE(SUBSTRING("PunchIn = '2019-06-10 09:10:00'" FROM 11 FOR 21));`

Comment: I do not think the whole string is the value. The TO wrote that he has a column of type timestamp not of text. I think his column is named PunchIn and the timestamp is the value.

Comment: I had to substring because he said extracting date value from the whole string. That was my understanding of course. A clarification is required.